# Is there a way to install a package available in Ubuntu Karmic on Ubuntu Precise Pangolin?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, downgrade, 9.10, fortran

I want to install `gfortran-4.4.1` on *Ubuntu 12.04 (**Precise Pangolin**)*. But the only versions available in repositories are 4.4.7, 4.5 and 4.6. 
However `gfortran-4.4.1` can be easily installed via `apt-get` on *Ubuntu 9.10 (**Karmic**)*.

So I tried, to replace `etc/apt/sources.list` with the one from *Karmic*. When I did `sudo apt-get update` everything worked fine, but when I tried to install `gfortran` I kept getting error messages like:

> Depends: [package name] but it is not going to be installed.

I tried to remove those packages and reinstall older version of them, but it didn't seem to help.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Any comments on that?

Comment: packages are build for specific versions.They don't work on other versions.You may get the source code for karmic and rebuild it for pangolin.But outright installation will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in @Registered User comment:
The answer is there is no  way to install a package available in Ubuntu Karmic on Ubuntu Precise Pangolin.

You CAN however build from the Karmic source code.

You can also run Karmic on a VM under Virtual box and install and run your favourite Karmic apps in that fashion.